# How to set a select option as selected when the data source is dynamically generated in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webforms

I have the following code

```html
<select ng-model="someObj.SomeEligibleStatusId" ng-options="st.someId as st.someDescription for st in someFunctionThatGeneratesData()"></select>
```

where `someFunctionThatGeneratesData(param1, param2, param3)` returns an array of objects such as

```
[
   {
      "someId":1,
      "someDescription":"Test 1"
   },
   {
      "someId":2,
      "someDescription":"Test 2"
   }
]
```

and I'm trying to change the selected option in javascript as

```js
someObj.SomeEligibleStatusId = 1
```

without luck. I try also to add "track by", bind it to an object item of the array, and a couple of more scenarios... I'm losing it here guys. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.selectedsomeId = $someFunctionThatGeneratesData.options[1];

<select data-ng-model="selectedsomeId" 
        ng-options="st.someId as st.someDescription for st in someFunctionThatGeneratesData()"></select>
```